# apply a function n times to the n-th item in a list in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, higher-order-functions

I want a higher-order function, g,  that will apply another function, f, to a list of integers such that

```
g = [f x1, f(f x2), f(f(f x3)), … , f^n(xn)]
```

I know I can map a function like

```
g :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
g f xs = map f xs
```

and I could also apply a function n-times like

```
g f xs = [iterate f x !! n | x <- xs]
```

where n the number of times to apply the function. I know I need to use recursion, so I don't think either of these options will be useful.

Expected output:

```
g (+1) [1,2,3,4,5] = [2,4,6,8,10]
```

Comment: I can't help feeling that `[x0, f x1, f (f x2), ...]` -- i.e., one less `f` everywhere -- would be a more natural pattern.

Comment: @DanielWagner, either is fine, but don't pull a `scanl`-style both.

Comment: @dfeuer Oh, you mean I'm not the only one that feels like `scanl` always has one more element than I wanted on the front?

Comment: @DanielWagner, nope. `mapAccumL` gets that right, but then it spoils fusion on the way out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with explicit recursion where you pass each time the function to apply and the tail of the list, so:

```
g :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
g f = go f
    where go _ [] = []
          go fi (x:xs) = … : go (f . fi) xs
```

I here leave implementing the `…` part as an exercise.

Another option is to work with two lists, a list of functions and a list of values. In that case the list of functions is `iterate (f .) f`: an infinite list of functions that can be applied. Then we can implement `g` as:

```
g :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
g f = zipWith ($) (iterate (f .) f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've got something like `go fi (x:xs) = f x : g (f . fi) xs` but I get `g (+1) [1,2,3,4,5] = [2,4,7,12,21]` instead of `[2,4,6,8,10]` It looks like its going up by powers of two.

Comment: @jamie: I made a typo, it is `: go (f . fi) xs`, not `: g (f . fi) xs`

Comment: Now I am getting `g (+1) [1,2,3,4,5] = [2,3,4,5,6]` which just appears to be a mapping. Have I done something wrong with `go fi (x:xs) = f x`? Your second implementation works.

Comment: @jamie: you made a mistake, it is not `f x`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like another use for foldr:

```
applyAsDeep :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
applyAsDeep f = foldr (\x xs -> f x : map f xs) []

λ> applyAsDeep (+10) [1,2,3,4,5]
[11,22,33,44,55]
```

Comment: This looks nice, but it's actually really inefficient. Can you see why? You can fix it while still using `foldr`, but it needs to be structured differently.

Comment: Mapping over and over?

Comment: Yup. Each `(:)` constructor in the result will take longer to produce than the last one.

Comment: Yeah, I need to put the complexity in pen and paper. Get back afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go a bit overkill ...

```hs
import GHC.Exts (build)

g :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
g f xs0 = 
  build $ \c n -> 
    let go x r fi = fi x `c` r (f . fi) 
    in foldr go (const n) xs0 f
```

Comment: Did you mean GHC.Base (build) ? https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=build%20package%3Abase

Comment: @pedrofurla, I could've sworn that came from `GHC.List`. Fixed now!

Comment: Just noticed it is not compiling. the where is "driving it crazy". Going to edit with one that compiles.

Comment: To benefit the curious an explanation about `build` https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/build.md

Comment: @pedrofurla, that's what I get for punching in code on my phone. Thanks for the fixes.